# How should i solved w3c validation error?

Tags: w3c-validation

I am new to w3c error solving i am trying solve this url https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iasio.ie%2F but when i remove data where error occur then still it came w3c is there any cache issue.  here is have attached screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Add a closing div tag where it belongs, most likely just before the closing form tag.

Comment: thank you for reply ,yes i also did that but my question is when i am doing that changes it doesn't show while i revalidate

Comment: when i remove this all form than still it shown in my validation page is there any cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have caching.  Just change the URL slightly, like this: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iasio.ie%2F%3Ffoo%3D1